# How to write into two different files simultaneously using boost logging libraries in c++?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am writting a logging application usingn Boost where i need to write two different logs in to two different file. Ex. My performance log will go to Performance.log file and application log will go to application.log file.

Created two file_sink_ptr which points to two different files. Added the sink pointer to the core.

Using individual sink ptr, i am logging each type of logs.

I am seeing two files created and both having the same logs.
I need to have the application logs in file1 and performance log in file2. But here no segregation is happening. Both application and performance logs are going to both files.

Can you please help with this.

```
typedef boost::log::sinks::asynchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< file_sink >  file_sink_ptr;
file_sink_ptr sinkptr1 = boost::make_shared<file_sink >(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = fileName
        boost::log::keywords::target = dirName,
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true);

sinkptr1->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(boost::log::sinks::file::make_collector(
        boost::log::keywords::target = dirName,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = dirSize));


--------------2nd file
file_sink_ptr sinkptr2 = boost::make_shared<file_sink >(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = fileName2
        boost::log::keywords::target = dirName,
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true);

sinkptr2->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(boost::log::sinks::file::make_collector(
        boost::log::keywords::target = dirName,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = dirSize));

sinkptr1->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    sinkptr2->locked_backend()->auto_flush();

boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sinkptr1);
boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sinkptr2);
LogData* ptr1 = new LogData();
ptr1->sinkPtr = sinkptr1;

LogData* ptr2 = new LogData();
ptr2->sinkPtr = sinkptr2;

----------------------------------------------
 struct LogData
    {
        boost::log::sources::logger         logger;
        file_sink_ptr                       sinkPtr;
    };


BOOST_LOG(ptr1 ->logger) << StringTextMessage1;
BOOST_LOG(ptr2 ->logger) << StringTextMessage2;
```

Comment: Where do you distinguish between what goes to the app log and what goes to the performance log?

Comment: `void ua::AnalyticsAdvancedLogger::WriteLine( LPCTSTR lpszLine , int isSystemMonitor)
{
 if (isSystemMonitor)
  BOOST_LOG(ptr1->logger << msg string;
 else
  BOOST_LOG( ptr2->logger ) << msg string; 
}`